# search algorithm in phone contacts android

Tags: android, algorithm, search, android-contacts

in my application I get a list of contacts from the phone.
I need to implement a context filter / search mechanism through the list of contacts.

FILTER CONDITION:
Filter by contact name in accordance with the letters of which are located on the numeric keys (all possible combinations)!

When i enter each new number list should be changed leaving only suitable contacts.

Like here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXZmJ.png

I input "253" and application finds to me ALE.
Please help me to do this.

```
private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
private List<Contact> sortContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
int textlength = 0;
TextView textView;

private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        textlength = textView.getText().length();

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            if (textlength <= contacts.get(i).getName().length()) {
                            // need help here
                                                                       }}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) to get all strings with a certain perfix.

Note however, that in your case - you are checking for a number of prefixes in each search, a possible solution is holding a trie of the numbers representing the strings, and the lead of the trie will point to the strings it actually represents (there could be more then once).

When looking for a number, use a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) from the prefix number to get all relevant strings.

If the list of names is not changing too often, a trie might be an overkill. You can instead store tuples `(number,string)` where `number` is the representing number and `string` is the name in a sorted array, and use [binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) to get the first number with the needed prefix, and just return all names with it with linear search once it is found.

Note however, that inserting a new entry in this case will be `O(n)`, so if it does happen often - avoid this solution, since it is expected to be not efficient.